# Create frequency table per group

Tags: r

In R, I have a data.frame with an ID, period, and a couple of variables of which the year is given.

[image: df]

```
df <- structure(list(id = 10001:10010, 
                     period = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), 
                                        .Label = c("2017-01", "2017-02"), class = "factor"), 
                     year1 = c(2013, 2014, 2014, 2017, 1970, 2014, 1970, 2014, 2014, 1970), 
                     year2 = c(2015, NA, 2015, 2015, 1970, 1970, 2014, 2017, 2014, 2017), 
                     year3 = c(2015, 2014, 2015, NA, NA, 2014, 2014, 2015, 1970, 2014), 
                     year4 = c(1970, 2014, 2013, 2014, 1970, 1970, 2014, 2015, 2015, NA)), 
                .Names = c("id", "period", "year1", "year2", "year3", "year4"), 
                row.names = c(NA, -10L), 
                class = "data.frame")
```

What I would like to achieve, is to create a data.frame in which, for every period and for everyvariable (year1-year4), a frequency is shown how often a specific year (1970,2013-2017) is shown.
The desired result should be something like this:

[image: result]

```
result <- structure(list(period = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
                                            .Label = c("2017-01", "2017-02"), 
                                            class = "factor"), 
                         category = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), 
                                              .Label = c("year1", "year2", "year3", "year4"), 
                                              class = "factor"), 
                         X1970 = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
                         X2013 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
                         X2014 = c(3L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
                         X2015 = c(0L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), 
                         X2017 = c(1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), 
                    .Names = c("period", "category", "X1970", "X2013", "X2014", "X2015", "X2017"), 
                    class = "data.frame", 
                    row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

I've got medium experience in R, and I'm confident this can be achieved. But I'm completely lost on how to approach this problem. Suggestions/ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly you can achieve this with the package `reshape2` by first turning the data from "wide" to "long" format via `melt` and then turning it back via `cast` while selecting the desired categories - I hope this is what you need.

```
df <- structure(list(id = 10001:10010, 
                     period = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), 
                                        .Label = c("2017-01", "2017-02"), class = "factor"), 
                     year1 = c(2013, 2014, 2014, 2017, 1970, 2014, 1970, 2014, 2014, 1970), 
                     year2 = c(2015, NA, 2015, 2015, 1970, 1970, 2014, 2017, 2014, 2017), 
                     year3 = c(2015, 2014, 2015, NA, NA, 2014, 2014, 2015, 1970, 2014), 
                     year4 = c(1970, 2014, 2013, 2014, 1970, 1970, 2014, 2015, 2015, NA)), 
                .Names = c("id", "period", "year1", "year2", "year3", "year4"), 
                row.names = c(NA, -10L), 
                class = "data.frame")



library(reshape2)
dcast(melt(df[,-1]), period + variable ~ value)

#     period variable 1970 2013 2014 2015 2017 NA
# 1 2017-01    year1    1    1    3    0    1  0
# 2 2017-01    year2    1    0    0    3    2  0
# 3 2017-01    year3    0    0    2    3    0  1
# 4 2017-01    year4    2    1    1    1    0  1
# 5 2017-02    year1    2    0    2    0    0  0
# 6 2017-02    year2    1    0    2    0    0  1
# 7 2017-02    year3    1    0    2    0    0  1
# 8 2017-02    year4    1    0    2    1    0  0
```

Comment: Yes, this is exacly what I was looking for.. The approach is so simple, that I'm a bit ashamed that I didnt'come up with it myself. THANKS!

Comment: You cannot know every package and its options that match your problem at all time. I also had this experience of tasks I stumbled with that were solved by others in one line. But that´s also what SO is for sometimes, so no worries, good luck with your project.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an idea using `tidyverse`,

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
 gather(category, val, -c(id, period)) %>% 
 na.omit() %>% 
 group_by(period, category, val) %>% 
 summarise(new = n()) %>% 
 spread(val, new, fill = 0)
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 8 x 7
> # Groups:   period, category [8]
>    period category `1970` `2013` `2014` `2015` `2017`
> *  <fctr>    <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
> 1 2017-01    year1      1      1      3      0      1
> 2 2017-01    year2      1      0      0      3      2
> 3 2017-01    year3      0      0      2      3      0
> 4 2017-01    year4      2      1      1      1      0
> 5 2017-02    year1      2      0      2      0      0
> 6 2017-02    year2      1      0      2      0      0
> 7 2017-02    year3      1      0      2      0      0
> 8 2017-02    year4      1      0      2      1      0
> ```

The main trick here is to convert to long format, calculate the frequencies, and convert back to wide format.

A bit shorter version, utilizing the `count` function (as @markdly mentions), can be,

```
df %>% 
 gather(category, val, -c(id, period)) %>% 
 na.omit() %>% 
 count(period, category, val) %>% 
 spread(val, n, fill = 0)
```

Comment: And if you wanted to shorten this slightly you could possibly do `count(period, category, val) %>% spread(val, n, fill = 0)` instead of the `group_by` step onwards...

Comment: Thanks you, your code is easy to follow! While I'm a big fan of the tidyverse, I have to mark the answer from Manual as the acepted answer, because it is so fast, and so short :).
Thank you very much for your help though!!! I've never used "gather" before, will look into it!

Comment: No problem. Happy to help :)

Comment: Please note that the package `reshape2` is a precedent of the larger package set `tydiverse` by [Hadley Wickham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16632/hadley). I am not sure, but I guess that in the background of @Sotos solution, the code of `reshape2` is run or at least reused. Would have to check that on github. Hence, the solutions are probably quite similar concerning the code in the background. However, an advantage about `reshape2` can be that it goes very well with `data.table` if you intend to use this package.